# Allow removal of force installed Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-workspace, google-chrome-extensions

As an Administrator of my Google Apps Organisation I want to be able to manage a suite of Chrome extensions that are either crucial to the work environment or that are very useful.

I want this set of extensions to be easily or automatically installed for each user, but I also want each user to have the ability to disable any of these extensions if they wish to.

Currently I'm using the Force Install option to initialise each user with the set of extensions, but unfortunately this doesn't allow them to disable any of those extensions.

Is there either a way to allow them to disable extensions I've set to force install, or a better way of providing them with a suite of extensions for easy install.